# How to change Angular-UI Bootstrap Datepicker popup's style using CSS?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using `ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js`. I changed dropdown-menu's backgorund color like this in specific html.

```
.dropdown-menu {
   background-color: transparent;
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

But it makes datepicker's background transparent too. I know why it happened, so I cleared that line but nothing changed.

So I want to change datepicker popup's background using CSS selector like this,

```
.datepicker .ul{
    background-color: white;
}
//this is an example code.
```

what selector do I have to choose to change datepicker's background?

[image: this is present situation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

If this is what you require, you need to add these two styles that are highlighted.

Happy coding :)

Comment: thanks! Now I see it has lots of classes in same level.